# Como posso criar uma tela com Views diferentes para relatório c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

é o seguinte tenho um sistema que tem alguns relatórios queria fazer uma única tela (webForm) e conforme o usuário faz uma chamada do relatório a tela gera esse relatório e mostra na tela.

Answer (score 1):

Na sua página, você pode criar um form com as opções de relatórios do seu sistema.
O usuário seleciona uma das opções e clica em um botão.
No botão, você pode verificar qual a opção do relatório que foi escolhido e renderizar aquele relatório.
Segue um exemplo de como renderizar o report:

```
reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;

    ServerReport serverReport = reportViewer.ServerReport;

    // Define o servidor do SSRS e qual o report:
    serverReport.ReportServerUrl =
        new Uri("http://<Server Name>/reportserver");
    serverReport.ReportPath =
        "/AdventureWorks Sample Reports/Sales Order Detail";

    // Cria variavel com parâmetros do relatório
    ReportParameter salesOrderNumber = new ReportParameter();
    salesOrderNumber.Name = "SalesOrderNumber";
    salesOrderNumber.Values.Add("SO43661");

    // Seta os parâmetros ao relatório.
    reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(
        new ReportParameter[] { salesOrderNumber });
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337091.aspx